# Mysql not opening

Tags: mysql

I am using xampp package on windows 8. When I am starting mysql I am getting this issue in error log.

> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 1030 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 7359127 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery. 
>   2013-09-02 12:17:16 4320 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>
> 2013-09-02 12:17:17 4320 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a
>   previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace
>   mysql/slave_worker_info uses space ID: 5 at filepath:
>   .\mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace
>   pos/adminnotification_inbox which uses space ID: 5 at filepath:
>   .\pos\adminnotification_inbox.ibd InnoDB: Error: could not open
>   single-table tablespace file .\pos\adminnotification_inbox.ibd InnoDB:
>   We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>   InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log
>   to it. InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld: InnoDB: 1) If
>   there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot InnoDB:
>   open the file, you should modify the permissions. InnoDB: 2) If the
>   table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup, InnoDB: then
>   you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal InnoDB:
>   crash recovery and ignore that table. InnoDB: 3) If the file system or
>   the disk is broken, and you cannot remove InnoDB: the .ibd file, you
>   can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf InnoDB: and force InnoDB
>   to continue crash recovery here.

Answer (score 2):

Please Reinstall it. this is mainly for missing and currepted files..

Comment: Will I be able to backup my database?

Comment: It is happening to me so often. Can you tell me why it happens?